# How to Delete a file at a specified date

Tags: windows, batch, scheduled-tasks

I want to delete a file (a .exe) from a folder, after a specified date, say 25/Feb/2010. How can I use scheduled tasks and batch files for this. I am not sure whether the code below work :

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
CD c:\target_folder\
ECHO Y | DEL innocent.exe
```

Will it work? If not, what will?

And how to run it on or after a specified date?
Another doubt is how to go about adding it to scheduled tasks? Will it work if I don't turn the system ON, on 25/FEB? My requirement is this, the file should be deleted after that date.

Answer (score 1):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565

Summary: Use the at [time] [command] command.

Example:

bat1.bat:

```
at 2400 25 bat2.bat
```

bat2.bat:

```
#Your code
```

These 2 .bat files will, every month on the 25th, run bat2.bat.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a unix system read this wikipedia article about [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). [This article](http://www.simonholywell.com/article/windows-cron-jobs-using-schtasks-or-at.html) gives some ideas on how to get the same effect in windows. Looks like basically  Start > Programs > Accessories > System Tools > Scheduled Tasks.

Answer (score 0):

[How To Schedule Tasks in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569)

From the command line: [Schtasks](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/schtasks.mspx?mfr=true)